# Create a random graph or its corresponding adjacency matrix from a given degree list

Tags: r, igraph, random, adjacency-matrix, digraphs

I have the following problem in R:
I have a vector that contains the degrees of 200 nodes in my graph. Strictly speaking should they present out-degrees.
Is it possible to create from these existing degrees for the nodes i = 1, ...,200 a random graph and its adjacency matrix?

As an example some degrees of the vector are entered below:

118 134 120 124 102 100 126 123 112 3 3 4 6 4 4 2 3 2 3 8 5 3 2 4 5 7
3 4 5 8 3 4 2 9 0 1 4 4 4 6 5 2 2 4 4 7 6 5 5 5 3 3 4 5 5 5 1 3 6 4 8 7 9 6 3 2 3 6 4 7 2 8 7 6 9 3 1 3 [...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `sample_degseq` from `igraph`:

```
library(igraph)
outdegrees <- c(2, 1, 1, 2, 4)
g <- sample_degseq(outdegrees, method = "simple.no.multiple")
get.adjacency(g)
# 5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
# 
# [1,] . . . 1 1
# [2,] . . . . 1
# [3,] . . . . 1
# [4,] 1 . . . 1
# [5,] 1 1 1 1 .
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey lukeA, Thanks for your help. It seems to be a useful procedure to solve my problem.  
However, there is still another problem. Once I run the code with the command "simple.no.multiedges", the R software collapses on my notebook and I have to restart the program.

Comment: @Fulla I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: purpose is to create a graph with a core-periphery structure. For this is a 'Concentracion parameter' Lambda that include information about the degree quantities of the few hubs ( d_b ) in the network.
These hubs have an expected value of E ( d_b ) = lambda * E ( d_s ) . E ( d_s ) is the expected value of the number of nodes with a low number of connections (-> low degree). These are randomly drawn from a Poisson distribution.

Comment: Thanks, interesting snippet. `sample_degseq(D, D, method = "simple")` creates a graph successfully here. Maybe you wanna add the code to your question, so others, who may find it useful, will find it more easily.

Comment: Sorry, i mean `sample_degseq(D, D, method = "simple.no.multiple"); ` instead